# Наибольшая общая подпоследовательность трех последовательностей

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть 3 строки. Нужно найти длину наибольшей общей подпоследовательности.

для двух строк я реализовал так:

```
def lcs(a, b):
lengths = [[0 for j in range(len(b)+1)] for i in range(len(a)+1)]
# row 0 and column 0 are initialized to 0 already
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    for j, y in enumerate(b):
        if x == y:
            lengths[i+1][j+1] = lengths[i][j] + 1
        else:
            lengths[i+1][j+1] = max(lengths[i+1][j], lengths[i][j+1])
# read the substring out from the matrix
return lengths[len(a)][len(b)]
```

для трех пробую так же, но через 3 мерную матрицу:

```
def lcs(a, b, c):
lengths = [[[0 for j in range(len(b) + 1)] for i in range(len(a) + 1)] for k in range(len(c) + 1)]
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    for j, y in enumerate(b):
        for k, z in enumerate(c):
            if x == y == z:
                lengths[i + 1][j + 1][k + 1] = lengths[i][j][k] + 1
            else:
                lengths[i + 1][j + 1][k + 1] = max(lengths[i + 1][j][k], lengths[i][j + 1][k], lengths[i][j][k+1])
return lengths[len(a)][len(b)][len(c)]
```

но для 3х строк не считает. Как это можно переделать?

Answer (score 1):

не правильно проверял смещение по матрице:

```
 lengths[i + 1][j + 1][k + 1] = 
             max(lengths[i + 1][j][k], lengths[i][j + 1][k], lengths[i][j][k+1])
```

так правильно:

```
lengths[i + 1][j + 1][k + 1] = 
             max(lengths[i + 1][j][k], lengths[i][j + 1][k], lengths[i][j][k+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Для набора из произвольного числа строк можно сделать так:

```
def lcs(strings):
    count = len(strings)
    if count == 0:
        return None
    if count == 1:
        return strings[0]
    strings = sorted(strings, key=len)
    len0 = len(strings[0])
    if len0 == 0:
        return strings[0]

    for currentLength in range(len0, 0, -1):
        for startIndex in range(len0 - currentLength + 1):
            foundString = strings[0][startIndex:startIndex+currentLength]
            found = [False] * (count - 1)
            for stringNumber in range(1, count):
                string = strings[stringNumber]
                for startIndex2 in range(len(string) - currentLength + 1):
                    if string[startIndex2:startIndex2+currentLength] == foundString:
                        found[stringNumber-1] = True
                        break
                if not found[stringNumber-1]:
                    break
            if all(f for f in found):
                return foundString
    return None
```

Метод работает не только со строками, но также и с произвольными итерируемыми объектами. Есть один небольшой недостаток - если совпадений несколько, вернёт первое встретившееся.

Если ограничиваться только строками, то можно немного упростить код, используя стандартные методы работы со строками. Цикл будет выглядеть так:

```
for currentLength in range(len0, 0, -1):
    for startIndex in range(len0 - currentLength + 1):
        foundString = strings[0][startIndex:startIndex+currentLength]
        found = [False] * (count - 1)
        for stringNumber in range(1, count):
            found[stringNumber-1] = strings[stringNumber].find(foundString) > 0
            if not found[stringNumber-1]:
                break
        if all(f for f in found):
            return foundString
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько моментов по алгоритму.
1. Поиск ускоряется, если отсортировать строки по возрастанию длины (функция `usort()`).
2. Задачу можно упростить, если воспользоваться стандартными функциями для вырезания подстроки `substr()` и для поиска этой подстроки в других строках `strpos()`.
3. Алгоритм для произвольного числа строк такой же, как и для трёх.

Программа на PHP выглядит так:

```
$common = ["abrakadabra", "brakodel", "dikobraz", "ubranstvo"];

function subs($str_sort, $k){
    $str_sort_size = count($str_sort);
    $len_max = strlen($str_sort[0])-$k;
    $length = 0;
    for ($len = 1; $len < $len_max; $len++){ 
        $sub = substr($str_sort[0], $k, $len);
        for($index = 1; $index < $str_sort_size - 1; $index++){
            if(strpos($str_sort[$index], $sub) === FALSE){
                return $length;
            }
        }
        $length = $len;
    }
    return $length;
};

$ucommon = $common;
usort($ucommon, function($s1,$s2){
    return strlen($s1) - strlen($s2);
});

var_dump($ucommon);
$k_max = -1;
$l_max = -1;
for($k = 0; $k < strlen($ucommon[0]); $k++){
    if(($l = subs($ucommon, $k)) > $l_max) {
        $k_max = $k;
        $l_max = $l;    
    }               
}

printf("Подстрока; %s Длина: $l_max", substr($ucommon[0], $k_max, $l_max));
```

Результаты:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'dikobraz' (length=8)
  1 => string 'brakodel' (length=8)
  2 => string 'ubranstvo' (length=9)
  3 => string 'abrakadabra' (length=11)
Подстрока; bra Длина: 3
```